# ModuleNotFoundError with Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I downloaded spyder and practicing I have tried to use commands that generate an error.

The command is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import dataset, linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
boston = datasets, load_boston()
print(boston)
print()
```

and spyder says:

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/temp.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\HP\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'


runcell(0, 'C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/temp.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\HP\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Where did you import load_boston()?

Comment: And do you think you *have* installed `matplotlib`?

Comment: I was trying to replicate the code of a course, it didn't matter anywhere, I don't know if the numpy, matplotlib and sklearn libraries were imported

Answer (score 0):

You should install matplotlib into spyder via the pip.exe from the spyder package.

```
C:\Users\Ann>cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\pip-19.2.3-py37_0\Scripts
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\pip-19.2.3-py37_0\Scripts>pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: import numpy as np
from sklearn import dataset, linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
boston = datasets, load_boston()
print(boston)
print()

Comment: search pip.exe in your pc. Make sure the path of the pip.exe is in the spyder folder. copy the path of pip.exe, go to your cmd, type cd, then paste. finally, enter 'pip install matplotlib'

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it was resolved after I used the `CMD.exe Prompt` from the Anaconda navigator on Windows 10.

Note that I already had it installed fine through the windows command prompt, outside Anaconda.